# Failed to discover available identity in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-keystone

I have a little problem with OpenStack installation.
When i use this:

```
openstack service list
```

the terminal return this error:

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting 
http://controller:35357/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
```

what is the solution?

Comment: You need to read keystone and front end logs to see the true error... They're on /var/log/keystone/keystone.log and /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/horizon/horizon.log...

Without those informations, you cant possible know what error it is... Could be permission, database, wrong config files and a lot else... Another thing, check if rabbit-mq is running maybe it died...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your open stack services are working.

ps -ef | grep stack

Answer (score 1):

In my case, OS_CACERT env variable was missing

Example:

`OS_CACERT=/etc/ssl/certs/Trust_Root.pem`